Chrome does not display frames at high refresh rate
Recently, I was experimented with requestAnimationFrame API and came across on strange beviour of chrome.
Look at this (165hz):
In comparison with (60hz): 
At 165hz some frames are skipped, but not at 60hz.
I also wonder why the first frames are not displayed:

If there are people who can explain this?
Run this code in your html file:


<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      let rafPast = 0;
      const start = (rafTime) => {
        document.body.innerHTML = `
        <div>${rafTime - rafPast}</div>
        <div>rafPast: ${rafPast}</div>
        <div>rafTime: ${rafTime}</div>
    `;
        /// by this we can track where we are in timeline of devtools
        if (rafPast > 1000 && document.body.style.backgroundColor != "green") {
          console.log(`timestamps {rafPast: ${rafPast}, rafTime: ${rafTime}}`);
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
          setTimeout(() => {});
        }
        console.log(`global {rafPast: ${rafPast}, rafTime: ${rafTime}}`);
        requestAnimationFrame(start);
        rafPast = rafTime;
      };
      requestAnimationFrame(start);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>requestAnimationFrame Test</p>
  </body>
</html>




@Yogi I attached the code of test file.

You can always report this in the devtools issue tracker
